# Message box OkOnly not working when closing application

Tags: vb.net, forms

I want to check if a certain criteria is met when user tries to close application. If criteria is met, application can close, if not, cannot close. I tried put the code FormClosing event, but when I press ok, it closes the application regardless of the condition.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim statusschimb As String = functiicomune.statusschimb()
    If statusschimb <> "Inchis" Then
        MsgBox("Schimbul nu este inchis! Va rugam inchideti schimbul!" & vbNewLine & "Instrumente --> Inchide schimb", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Atentie")
        If DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The MsgBox() function has a return value, do not ignore it.

Comment: `If (MsgBox(...) = MsgBoxResult.Ok) Then` ...

Comment: thanks both of you. works now!